# safe to setup NAS in virtual image with web server?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, nas, webserver, freenas

My current setup is Ubuntu Desktop, running Apache + MySQL + PHP stack.  I use this image to host my small website to the outside world.

I want to now run a virtual machine on the box, that will act as the FreeNAS box for my internal network.  This sounds like a bad idea if the website gets hacked/attacked.  Should I just give up and grab a dedicated machine instead?  Can I instead virtualize the web server and NAS side by side on this machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your virtual machine, if properly isolated from your web services, wouldn't likely be vulnerable to attack unless your entire machine / root account were compromised.

That said, if you're concerned about data performance/reliability/resiliency on the NAS instance, you're going to find that running your NAS off of a virtual machine with (unknown) specs is probably going to cause you more headache than it's worth if you're hosting existing server-services on the host OS.

If your specs on the existing desktop are less than spectacular, you'd be better too obtain a new dedicated box for your NAS. If your specs are high-end, you may want to consider a hypervisor solution (like VMware ESXi) and virtualize both your web server and your NAS in isolation on top of ESXi.

Comment: ESXi was a thought, thanks for the explanation.  My box is a consumer grade CPU (AMD A10), 8GB RAM, and a 350GB spare spin drive by Western Digital.  If performance is a concern, it sounds like I should just save up and get a dedicated 1U NAS.

Comment: You can find some pretty affordable 5-disk ones out there -- consumer grade of course, but still not super pricey. Good luck!